# Docker Always force to use a cached image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to build my application using docker.

Version of docker-compose is 2.2

I have all the containers running well at the moment where one of the container has nginx running.

I need to change some configuration on this container.

The way I need to do (because of special scenario) is, to update the config inside the container.

Then I commit the container to build a new image.

```
docker commit <container> <image-name>
```

Now I have new image with tag latest.

What I want is to use this image when I run, docker-compose down && docker-compose up --build next time.

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up --build -d
```

With --build option, docker-compose will go through the steps in Dockerfile and run those and all my changes will be reverted.

**Question:**
Is there anyway that I can tell docker-compose to use the newly created image as cache and ignore Dockerfile for this one container?

Solution Tried: 
I have tried with docker-compose-override and using option cache-from and it's not working.

```
docker-compose.override.yml

container:
    build:
      cache_from:
         - new-image:latest
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused by this workflow.  Whatever the file change is, you can't have your Dockerfile setup make it for you?

Comment: No, that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to build an image from docker-compose even though you have already built it by docker-commit.

> Now I have new image with tag latest.
>   What I want is to use this image when I run, docker-compose down && docker-compose up

If you have already built image, skip the `build` phase in docker-compose.  Just specify which image should be used like so:

```
container:
    image: new-image:latest
    container_name: "Foo bar"
    .....(other options)
```

> [**Image**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image)
>
> Specify the image to start the container from. Can either be a
>   repository/tag or a partial image ID.
>
> ```
> image: redis
> image: ubuntu:14.04
> image: tutum/influxdb
> image: example-registry.com:4000/postgresql
> image: a4bc65fd
> ```
>
> If the image does
>   not exist, Compose attempts to pull it, unless you have also specified
>   build, in which case it builds it using the specified options and tags
>   it with the specified tag.

If you have any other images that you build from inside docker-compose run:

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

If not simple `docker-compose up` will suffice.