# Docker buildx is not caching bundle install line but runs it each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, macos, apple-m1, buildx

I'm using buildx because I'm doing my development on an macbook and my company's server runs on an intel platform.  If there's some way to build docker images for my company's server other than using buildx, I'm open to it.

Anyway, every time I build the container, it builds it from scratch.  This means downloading **docker.io/library/ruby:3.1.4-bullseye** every single time, and running **RUN bundle install** every single time.  This is a huge pain and takes forever, especially in low-bandwidth scenarios.  It does this even if I don't change anything in the folder before executing the build.  Like I log off one day, log back on the next day, and build the container *(without changing anything)*, it rebuilds the entire thing from scratch.

This is the command I'm using to build :

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --push -t registry.digitalocean.com/[MY COMPANY NAME]/[MY IMAGE NAME] .
```

Thing is, I'm pretty sure docker isn't supposed to work this way.  From my understanding, it's supposed to cache the layers of the file system, and only rebuild the layer that you change (and every layer after that).  At very least, it shouldn't have to do a full rebuild if you change nothing in the directory at all.

Could this have something to do with Ruby on Rails?  I know it's not the most common platform anymore, but I can't be the only person developing a Rails app on a Macbook.  I can't imagine everybody puts up with the situation I've been dealing with.

Any suggestions?

I tried doing the build on my server (as opposed to on my macbook) and it did exactly the same thing.

Edited to add : here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.1.4-bullseye

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y nano postgresql-client postgresql-client-common bash

# Default directory
ENV INSTALL_PATH /opt/[MY PROJECT]
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3001"]
```

Comment: This would probably be a little bit easier with a dockerfile included, so people can point out where the "no caching behaviour" comes from potentially

Comment: "Like I log off one day, log back on the next day" there's no way for us to know what happens in your environment outside of what you've provided in the question.

Comment: In case of ```docker-compose``` it should be enough to refer an image by name to prevent its build from scratch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205782/docker-always-force-to-use-a-cached-image . In case of single image, after you build once it should be available over ```docker ps -a``` https://duckduckgo.com/?q=docker+show+all+containers&t=newext&atb=v299-1&ia=web. So you will need to just run it instead of building again https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_start/

Comment: @BMitch My point is that it always rebuilds from scratch, no matter what.  Even if I just do a build, wait 10 seconds, change one character in one file, and then build again, it always builds the entire thing from scratch.  The thing that stands out the most is the fact that it rebuilds the entire image from scratch, even if i made my change to one of the "upper" layers of the file system.  If I made my change to an "upper" layer, why should it have to rebuild the "lower" layers?

Answer (score 1):

First, one observation: I would install your OS dependencies before your gem dependencies, as some of them may be important for the gems (e.g. postgresql)

I think you have two questions here:

1. why is it not caching the add and run layers as you expect
2. what can you do about it (workarounds etc)

Q1) why is it not caching the add and run layers as you expect

My guess is that when docker does the `RUN bundle install` it will end up modifying the Gemfile.lock (e.g. maybe the version of bundler is different, or the platform is different enough - these are both written into the lockfile by default - this varies from bundler version 1 to 2 so worth checking into). Worth verifying that this is the case.
If the Gemfile.lock is modified by the following line, then it's possible (I'm not 100% sure) that on the subsequent run, the `COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./` line will invalidate the cache of the subsequent lines (as it's changing the contents).

Q2) what can you do about it

(if the theory about Gemfile.lock being changed is correct:) Maybe you can run `bundler install` without changing the lockfile (e.g. `bundle install --production` or ensuring the versions match, or copying the changes across)

But a workaround no matter what is causing the lack of build caching is to  create an explicit interim build target. The most obvious way of doing this is to create a separate dockerfile just composed of your dependencies (first the os dependencies, then the copy of the gemfiles and bundle install).

```
# e.g. call it Dockerfile-dependencies
FROM ruby:3.1.4-bullseye

RUN apt-get -y update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y nano postgresql-client postgresql-client-common bash

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
```

Then you build this as (say) `PROJECT_NAME-dependencies` (`docker build -f Dockerfile-dependencies -t PROJECT_NAME-dependencies`) and you only need to rebuild this when your dependencies change (you can run `bundle check` in your docker to see if bundle install needs re-running) and then make this the base for your main dockerfile:

```
FROM PROJECT_NAME-dependencies
# Default directory
ENV INSTALL_PATH /opt/[MY PROJECT]
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3001"]
```

A more elegant way of doing this is with a multi-stage build -- see https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/07/12/docker-cache/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long delay, but late is better than never! Anyway, I did eventually get past this. It looks like bundler wanted to use the latest version, which is different from the version that ships with the bullseye ruby image. As a temporary fix, I edited my Gemfile.lock and changed the BUNDLED WITH line to 2.3.26, which is the version that ships with the docker image. and this seems to have worked.

Not a permanent fix, but at least I figured out what was causing the problem.